# What is .content in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing homework for my html class. And the book makes us insert some css. So I copy pasted it. Here it is.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Garamond;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #122973;
}
table {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-spacing:10px;
}
.menu {
    text-align: left;
    width: 20%;
}
.content {
    width: 80%;
}
```

But I don't understand what `.content` is. Or `.menu`. 
When I googled content, it showed me things like

```
content: open-quote;
content: close-quote;
content: no-open-quote;
content: no-close-quote;
```

Here's the solution image to my homework. 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/NeiegNM.png]
What part of that picture uses the .menu and .content rule?
In my homework it never said to give anything a class called content or menu.

Comment: Is the markup supplied by the homework assignment or something you are expected to write yourself?

Comment: Searching Google won't do anything for you, classes can be set to anything.

Comment: All of the css is given from the book.
The html we have to type. 
It just occurred to me that maybe we were supposed to use common sense and put those classes within the html. It slipped my mind because usually we just follow directions the entire way through. We never have to do anythign other than what the directions say.

Answer (score 3):

`.content` is just a class selector - it selects any element on the page that has a class of 'content'.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers preceeded by a dot (`.`) are class selectors. They refer to the value of a class attribute of an HTML elmement.

The page creator can make up these names themselves, so googling them is pointless. 'content' probably refers to the content section on the page, but you would have to check the HTML to be sure. Judging by the image you added, this seems about right, there is a menu which is about 20% wide and a content section that occupies the rest of the space.

So if your assignment is to write the HTML, you just have to apply the right styles to the right elements by adding `class="content"` to the proper elements.

Answer (score 1):

`.content` targets to a class selector.

HTML markup for:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

This can be used many times inside of a page, unlike `id` which should be unique per page.

Answer (score 0):

`content` and `menu` are the names of classes of elements within the HTML code of the page. Class names are prepended with a dot (`.`) when referenced in CSS.

This is a good resource for CSS selectors: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 0):

the ".content" references to the class "content", where you have all that text, and you are defining in that class that you want the content box to be 80% of the size of the website.